# Possible to send a warning about a (specific) changed file in Git?

Tags: git, ignore, gitignore

I have a file which needs certain lines for the production server (and those lines to be commented out on the backup server and personal boxes).  Since it doesn't seem possible for Git to exclude certain lines from a file, is there a way to issue some kind of warning to users that will notify them certain lines need to be uncommented when pushing to the production server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a `pre-receive` hook is probably what you want. They're just executable files, exit non-zero to cancel the push. See [`git help hooks`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html)

This seems like the type of thing that would be most appropriate for a pre-commit hook, however that would require some manual setup (at the *least* a symlink) for each fresh clone. If that wouldn't be an issue, it would probably be preferable to making people either rewrite commits when they forget or clutter your history with changes to those lines.